# What is the Difference between Visual Studio Team System and Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio

Sounds like a very simple question. But What is the difference between TFS and Visual Studio Team System ?

I know TFS is version control and VSTS is collection of tools for developers, architects, testers.

But is TFS a part of VSTS ??

Also what is Visual Studio Team Services ? How are these products different from one another.

Please explain as these things can be sometimes very confusing.

Comment: "TFS is version control" - No, TFS is *much* more than just version control.  I liken it to more of software project management system.  Source control is just one part of it.

Comment: TFS is an "application lifecycle management" tool.

Answer (score 4):

Very short: VSTS is online version of TFS, main purpose: service control: TFVC and Git, but also includes Agile tools, continuous integration and so on.

See more detaled information in [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/).

Answer (score 0):

Basically its local Server vs. Cloud. There are a lot of articles which can be found on the internet. eg. [this one](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/comparative-analysis-tfs-online-premise-abdul-haque-ansari).

One major drawback is the reduced possibilities of customizing your development process, WITs and so on. Here is a list of things you can't in VSTS: [Click](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/import-process/differences)

> But is TFS a part of VSTS ??

No - its an online version of TFS.

If you have more questions, feel free to ask - but try to be more specific.

Comment: what is Visual Studio Team System ?? I am asking Team System not Team Services.

Comment: Team System is an old offering name that's no longer in use and hasn't been for around a decade.